# threejs tubegeometry getpointat does not rotate

Tags: three.js, rotation

When I create a TubeGeometry object, I can call getPointAt(t) to get the points along the object.
Once I rotate the TubeGeometry however, when I then call getPointAt(t), the points are NOT rotated with the model?
The geometry DOES rotate and looks right, but the getPointAt function returns the original, unrotated points.
Is there a way to get them to rotate with the geometry?

Answer (score 1):

You created a `TubeGeometry` from a `path`, and a `mesh` from the `TubeGeometry`.

Now you want to call `getPointAt( t )` to get points along the tube mesh.

If the `mesh` has been rotated, then you need to apply the same transformation to the returned value from `getPointAt( t )` that is applied to the `mesh`.

```
var point = path.getPointAt( t ).applyMatrix4( mesh.matrixWorld );
```

`mesh.matrixWorld()` will be updated for you in the render loop. If there have been changes since the previous render, you will have to call `mesh.updateMatrixWorld()` yourself first.

three.js r.76

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.